# How to configure memcache with elastic cache in Drupal settings.php

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, drupal-8

I Have configured the memcache with external elastic cache url of amazonin settings.php

> $settings['memcache']['servers'] =
>   ['xxx-memcache.xxxx.xxx.xxx.cache.amazonaws.com:11211' => 'default'];
>   $settings['memcache']['bins'] = ['default' => 'default'];
>   $settings['memcache']['key_prefix'] = '';
>   $settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.memcache';

But i receive the below error

There may be a problem with your Memcache configuration. Please review README.txt and visit the Drupal admin page for more information.

Can any one help to fix this issue. Can any let me know where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# MemCache Configuration $conf['cache_backends'][] = './sites/xyz/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'xyzlive';
```

or https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache

Comment: can you suggest for drupal 8